# How to get the font path in the Assets folder

Tags: fonts, xamarin.android, itext, android-assets

I create a PDF document using itextsharp and I need to connect the fonts from the Assets folder. 
At the moment everything works when I throw fonts in the memory of the smartphone.

```
System.String ttf = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + 
"/arial.ttf";
var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(tttt, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 
BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
var font = new Font(baseFont, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.NORMAL);

doc.Add(new Paragraph(inf1, font));
```

But probably no one has these fonts in the memory of the smartphone :)

I tried to get the path to the Assets folder using the following code:

```
public static AssetManager Assets { get; private set; }

string ttf;
using (var asset = Assets.Open("arial.ttf"))
{
    var fontStream = new MemoryStream();
    asset.CopyTo(fontStream);
}
```

or another option:

```
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("arial.ttf")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

but in these cases there is a problem:
object reference not set to an instance of an object... 
on line

```
using (var asset = Assets.Open("arial.ttf"))
```

and

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("arial.ttf")))
```

Maybe there is some analog of the folder path, similar to the path to the Font in Windows ?

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
```

or maybe I can somehow use the resulting TypeFace

```
Android.Graphics.Typeface tf = Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "arial.ttf");
```

Tell me, please, how do I set the necessary fonts in a PDF document or how to find the path to the fonts ttf, that would be inserted into the line BaseFont :)

Comment: Try whether "file:///android_asset/fileName" is the right path

Comment: @LeoZhu Doesn't find such a path :( 
And similar too

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your above code in my understanding when you say it gives you `object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error, which means that you are not assigning a value to it and its null what you need to do to overcome that is simple;

After declaring the property

```
 public AssetManager AppAssets { get; private set; }
```

In your class constructor assign it a value:

```
AppAssets= this.ApplicationContext.Assets; // In an activity
AppAssets= this.Activity.ApplicationContext.Assets; // In a fragment
```

Once you do this the object reference error should go away,

Goodluck revert in case of queries.

Comment: It seems to have helped.
But I realized that StreamReader won't really help me, because I need to get the path to the file, not read It :)

Comment: Can you explain your end goal and then maybe I can help you better?

Comment: This result in the read path of the stream: 
 iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>. Therefore, I think that a different approach is needed.

Comment: Ignore the exception what is your end goal what are you trying to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that 
BaseFont.CreateFont()
Wants to get path to the font file not a stream.

I am also facing this issue. It works for sdcard but how to make it read from assets folder i do not know. As a workaround i copy it to the documents folder.